# iOS Safari input auto-capitalization bug

Tags: ios, html, forms, input, safari

I got really strange behavior on Safari iOS 7 (iPhone 5) with input elements that are embedded into a form.

Assume the type of the input element is "text" I expect iOS Safari zu capitalize the first character (its default behavior)

```
<input type="text"/>
```

Now when I wrap a form with an action around my input element the capitalization will not work under certain conditions (that I didnt fully understand yet)

```
<form action="/orderlogin">
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

The given given example will not capitalize, but when I change the action to "/orderlogi" (removing the last character) it will work again!

Working capitalization: http://jsfiddle.net/yf2DF/15/

Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/yf2DF/16/

(Open with iPhone)

I am kind of out of ideas now so I hope someone has any idea why this is happening

regards

Comment: Safari usually tries to be artificially intellectual in really different cases, and in this case it may realize (having 'login' word in action) that it is 'login' field, which should not be autocapitalized (in the same way this should not be done with password). Though, I don't think it documented anywhere (the same way it's difficult to understand how 'Reader' feature works) - just avoid that 'login' word, OR you can try add name for you `input` tag.

Comment: Yes, I figuered that out.. It works on some of my pages where I use different action-values. Though there is no possiblity of changing this behaviour (by adding `autocapitalize="on"` or anything similar to the elment. Sigh
Thx for your help :)